# Definition of Stratonovich Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a doubt in definition of the *Stratonovich integral*. In *"Stochastic Calculus for Finance"* by Steven Shreve, he defines it using the midpoint $\frac {(t_i+t_{i+1})}{2}$ of the subinterval $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$, and at many places like google and calculating Stratonovich integration of Brownian motion with respect to itself, they use the average of the value of the process at these two points $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$.

Are these two forms equivalent. If yes, then how (I tried this but found no way) and if not then why there is two different forms of definition. Any suggestion is highly appreciable.

Comment: it would we helpful if you would write write down both definitions in question  explicitely

Comment: '@Naveen Kumar' if my answer is correct could you mark it as such ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer changed multiple times. I am very indebted to user ***Chaos*** who finally convinced me that both definitions of the Stratonovich integral are equivalent.

In his book *Stochastic Calculus for Finance II* Steven Shreve defines in Exercise 4.4 on p. 191,  the Stratonovich integral as
$$\tag{0}
\int_0^TW_t\circ\,dW_t=\lim_{||\Pi||\to0}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}W_{t^*_j}(W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_j})\,,\quad\quad t^*_j=\frac{t_{j+1}+t_j}{2}.
$$
This is *not* in conflict with the definitions one can see elsewhere.
For example in **Karatzas & Shreve**, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*, Problem 2.29 on p. 148:
$$\tag{1}
S_T(\Pi):=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}[(1-\epsilon)W_{t_i}+\epsilon W_{t_{i+1}}](W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})
$$
and
$$
\int_0^TW_s\circ dW_s=\lim_{||\Pi||\to0}S_T(\Pi)\quad\text{ for }\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

- The OP in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4421869/definitions-of-the-stratonovich-integral-and-why-the-average-definition-is-arg?noredirect=1#comment9257079_4421869) lists further references with the two seemingly different definitions which can be very disturbing.
- Thanks to ***Chaos*** I was made aware of the book H.H. Kuo, *Introduction to Stochastic Integration*. Kuo's Theorem 8.3.7. on p. 123 states that for a Brownian motion $B$ and a continuous function $f(t,x)$ with continuous partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x^2}$ one has
  \begin{align}
  &\int_a^bf(t,B(t))\circ dB(t)\\
  &=\lim_{||\Delta_n||\to0}\sum_{i=1}^nf\Big(t^*_i,\frac{1}{2}(B(t_{i-1})+B(t_i))\Big)\Big(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})\Big)\\
  &=\lim_{||\Delta_n||\to0}\sum_{i=1}^nf\Big(t^*_i,B\Big(\frac{t_{i-1}+t_i}{2}\Big)\Big)\Big(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})\Big)
  \end{align}
  where (in Kuo's notation) $t_{i-1}\le t_i^*\le t_i, \Delta_n=\{t_0,t_1,...,t_n\}$ is a partition of the finite interval $[a,b]$ and
  $||\Delta_n||=\max_{1\le i\le n}(t_i-t_{i-1})$.

Comment: Thank you, In this case I also calculated the integral but my question is which approach (one is using ${t_j}^*$ and other is $({W(t_j) +W(t_{j+1})})/2$ is correct and are these two ways of calculating integral equivalent?

Comment: Notice that in term right above (3) we have (after taking summations) $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} W_{t^*_j}\left[W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t^*_j}\right]+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} W_{t^*_j}\left[W_{t^*_j}-W_{t_j}\right]=I_1+I_2.$$
Although it may look like $I_1$ will converge to the Itô integral it does not, notice that if we consider $n=2$ we would have $W_{t_0^*}[W_{\color{red}{t_1}}-W_{t_0^*}]+W_{\color{red}{t_1^*}}[W_{t_2}-W_{t_1^*}]$ as opposed to what we *should* have (if we are defining an Itô integral) $W_{t_0}[W_{\color{blue}{t_1}}-W_{t_0}]+W_{\color{blue}{t_1}}[W_{t_2}-W_{t_1}]$.

Comment: That is to say: the point evaluation in the second term of the sum must be equal to the upper limit of the increment in the first term of the sum.
This does not hold in your case and then $(3)$ is  incorrect.

Comment: Sounds like you found my mistake. Will revise this answer. Learned a lot. Yepp. You are ***totally*** correct.

Comment: I added some extra information to my answer that you may find interesting

Answer (score 1):

Let $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots <t_N=T$ be an arbitrary partition of the interval $[0,T]$ with $\|\pi\|:=\max_{i} |t_{i+1}-t_i|$.

Define  $t^*_i:=\frac{t_{i+1}+t_i}{2}$ and consider

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}W\left(t_i^*\right)[W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)]\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}[W(t_i^*)-W(t_i)][W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)]+\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} W(t_i)[W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)]=\mathcal I_1+\mathcal I_2
\end{align*}
We know that as $\|\pi\|\to 0$ the term $\mathcal I_2$ converges to $\int_0^T W(t)dW(t)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.
In order to prove the desired result it suffices to show that $\mathcal I_1$ converges in $L^2(\Omega)$ to $T/2$.

We start by noticing that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[\mathcal I_1\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\mathbb E\left([W(t_i^*)-W(t_i)][W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)]\right)&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} t_i^*\wedge t_{i+1}-t_i\wedge t_{i+1}-t_i^*\wedge t_{i}+t_i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}t_i^*-t_i=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\frac{t_{i+1}-t_i}{2}=T/2
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\|\mathcal I_1-T/2\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2= \mathbb V\left(\mathcal I_1\right)=\mathbb V\left(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}[W(t_i^*)-W(t_i)][W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)]\right),
\end{align*}
due to the disjointness of the intervals  in each term of the sum we can write the latter as
\begin{align*}
 \|\mathcal I_1-T/2\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2= \mathbb V\left(\mathcal I_1\right)&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\mathbb V\left([W(t_i^*)-W(t_i)][W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)]\right)\\
 &=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\mathbb V\left([W(t_i^*)-W(t_i)][(W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i^*))+(W(t_i^*)-W(t_i))]\right)
\end{align*}

Let $\Delta_*(i):=[W(t^*_i)-W(t_i)]$ and $\Delta^*(i):=[W(t_{i+1})-W(t^*_i)]$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\mathbb V\left(\Delta_*(i)[\Delta^*(i)+\Delta_*(i)]\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\mathbb E\left(\Delta_*(i)^2[\Delta^*(i)+\Delta_*(i)]^2\right)- (t_i^*-t_i)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\mathbb E\left(\Delta_*(i)^2[\Delta^*(i)^2+2\Delta^*(i)\Delta_*(i)+\Delta_*(i)^2]\right)- (t_i^*-t_i)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\mathbb E\left(\Delta_*(i)^2\Delta^*(i)^2\right)+2E\left(\Delta^*(i)\Delta_*(i)^3\right)+\mathbb E\left(\Delta_*(i)^4\right)- (t_i^*-t_i)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\mathbb E\left(\Delta_*(i)^2\Delta^*(i)^2\right)+\mathbb E\left(\Delta_*(i)^4\right)- (t_i^*-t_i)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (t_i^*-t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i^*)+3(t_i^*-t_i)^2- (t_i^*-t_i)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (t_i^*-t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i^*)+2(t_i^*-t_i)^2
\end{align*}

Now notice that
\begin{align*}
(t_{i+1}-t_i^*)(t_i^*-t_i)= \left(t_{i+1}-\frac{t_i+t_{i+1}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{t_i+t_{i+1}}{2}-t_i\right)=\frac{(t_{i+1}-t_i)^2}{4},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
(t_i^*-t_i)^2=\frac{(t_{i+1}-t_i)^2}{4}
\end{align*}

and thus the latter equals

\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{4}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (t_{i+1}-t_i)^2\leq \frac{3}{4}\|\pi\|\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (t_{i+1}-t_i)=\frac{3}{4}\|\pi\|T
\end{align*}
and the last term on the right vanished as $\|\pi\|\to 0$.

EDIT:

An interesting property is that if we replace the standard product $\times$ in
$$\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}W\left(t_i^*\right)\times [W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)],$$
with the so-called *Wick product* "$\diamond$", then the choice of the evaluation point is irrelevant in fact
$$\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}W\left(t_i^{\alpha}\right)\diamond [W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)]\to \int_0^T W(t)dW(t)$$
where $t_i^{\alpha}:=[1-\alpha]t_{i}+\alpha t_{i+1}$ for any choice of $\alpha\in [0,1]$.

This is due to the fact that the Wick product is somehow implicit in the Itô integration via the formula

$$\int_0^T f(W(t))dW(t)=\int_0^T f(W(t))\diamond \dot W(t)dt$$
where $\dot W(t)$ denotes the distributional derivative of the Brownian motion (i.e. a white noise process).

Comment: Many thanks for this. In the meantime I bought Kuo's book. He does in fact have a theorem that relates the two definitions of the Stratonovich integral. I must read this carefully. So I did with your answer here. Since both answers can't be right, I am ***very puzzled***. I have edited my answer above again to make it more readable (hopefully). Would you mind trying to find a mistake there?

Comment: @KurtG. Of course! I'll try my best, and thanks for taking the time to go through all my calculations!