# Riemann–Stieltjes integral with itself.

Tags: integration, stieltjes-integral

Suppose that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous everywhere and non-decreasing. I am wondering that whether $$\int_a^b f(x)^{n-1}df(x) = \frac{1}{n}[f(b)^n-f(a)^n]$$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Notice that $f$ is not necessarily absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 1):

- When $f$ is non-decreasing and continuous it has bounded variation
  and therefore gives rise to a Riemann-Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral that satisfies
  the [integration by parts formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration#Integration_by_parts). In your case this can be written as
  $$\tag{1}
  \int_a^bf^{n-1}(x)\,df(x)=f^n(b)-f^n(a)-\int_a^bf(x)\,df^{n-1}(x)\,.
  $$
  This establishes your formula for
  $n=2\,.$ For  $n>2$ the formula follows from the

***Claim.***
$$\tag{2}
\int_a^bf(x)\,df^{n-1}(x)=(n-1)\int_a^b f^{n-1}(x)\,df(x)\,.
$$
Proof. Since $f$ is continuous and non-decreasing there is at most
one $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=0$ and $f\le 0$ ond $[a,c]$ and $f\ge 0$ on $[c,b]\,.$ By the additivity of the integral we can consider each
subinterval separately. Let's first consider the case $f\ge 0\,.$

We fix a partition $x_0<\dots<x_N$ of the interval and write
\begin{align}
f^k_i&:=f^k(x_i)\,,&
\Delta f^k_i=f^k_i-f^k_{i-1}\,.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\Delta f^{n-1}_i&=
f^{n-2}_{i-1}\,\Delta f^1_i+f^1_i\,\Delta f^{n-2}_i\,.
\end{align}
This leads easily to
\begin{align}\tag{3}
\Delta f^{n-1}_i
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}f^j_i\,f^{n-2-j}_{i-1}\,\Delta f^1_i\,.
\end{align}
Since $f$ is non-decreasing and $f\ge 0$ we have
$$
f^{n-2}_{i-1}\le f^j_i\,f^{n-2-j}_{i-1}
\le f^{n-2}_i\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$\tag{4}
\sum_{i=1}^Nf^{n-1}_{i-1}\,\Delta f^1_i\le \sum_{i=1}^Nf^{j+1}_i\,f^{n-2-j}_{i-1}\,\Delta f^1_i
\le \sum_{i=1}^Nf^{n-1}_i\,\Delta f^1_i\,.
$$
Both outer terms of (4) are [Riemann-Stieltjes sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) of
$$\tag{5}
\int_a^bf^{n-1}(x)\,df(x)\,
$$
and therefore converge to the same limit (5) (since the integrand
is continuous).
So does the middle term.
Looking at (3) it follows that the Riemann-Stieltjes sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^Nf_i\Delta f^{n-1}_i
$$
of $\int_a^bf(x)\,df^{n-1}(x)$
converges to
$$
(n-1)\int_a^b f(x)^{n-1}\,df(x)\,.
$$
This proves the claim for $f\ge 0\,.$ The case $f\le 0$ is handled analogously.

- When we drop the assumption that $f$ is non-decreasing the claim is generally wrong.

The prime example of a continuous but not absolutely continuous function is a Brownian path since it has infinite variation. We know from Ito's formula that
$$\int_a^b W_s\,dW_s=\frac{W_b^2-W_a^2-b+a}{2}\,$$ which is not of the form $\frac{W_b^2-W_a^2}{2}\,.$

If you want that this integral obeys standard calculus rules you should define it as Stratonovich integral
$$
\int_a^tW_s\circ\,dW_s
$$
which is obtained when the Riemann-Stieljes sums are defined as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{W_{t_{i+1}}+W_{t_i}}{2}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})\,
$$
or [equivalently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4214799/definition-of-stratonovich-integral/4215529#4215529) as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nW_{\textstyle\frac{t_{i+1}+t_i}{2}}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})\,.
$$

- When we assume that $f$ is non-decreasing but not absolutely continuous then the prime example is a Poisson process which is piecewise
  constant except when it has jumps of size one:
  $$
  \int_0^bN_{s-}\,dN_s=\sum_{n=1}^{N_b}(n-1)=\frac{N_b(N_b-1)}{2}\,.
  $$
  This shows that
  $$
  \int_a^bN_{s-}\,dN_s=\frac{N_b^2-N_a^2-N_b+N_a}{2}
  $$
  which is not of the form
  $$
  \int_a^bN_{s-}\,dN_s=\frac{N_b^2-N_a^2}{2}\,.
  $$
  Then again $N_t$ is not continuous as OP has assumed. Nonetheless,
  I find these examples important to know about.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. f in the claim needs to be continuous ‘everywhere’ and non-decreasing. Does Brownian motion so?

Comment: This seemingly just shows why we cannot drop the "non-decreasing" condition on $f$, in order for the integral to exist in the sense of Riemann-Stieltjes.

Comment: @EconKR00 I overread the non decreasing part.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, $f$ need not be absolutely continuous.  We can see this using the standard example of a singular function: [the Cantor staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks. Good point. Found another proof.